# Find all values of $x$ at which $P(x)=x^4-4x^3+22x^2-36x+18$ is a perfect square

Tags: polynomials

Find all values  of  positive  integer  $x$ at which  the following  expression is perfect  square

$$P(x)=x^4-4x^3+22x^2-36x+18$$

I tried  to assume $P= (x^2+ax+b)^2$  ;  and  comparing the cofactors , get that $a= -2 ; b= 9$ 
, but when expand the $x^2-2x+9$,  I didn't get  the same as $P$

What is wrong in my work?

Comment: In the statement of the problem, you neglected to specify the restrictions on $x$.

Comment: Why do you assume that the given polynomial can be written as a perfect square? There are plenty of x values that do not produce a function value that are squares. For example, x=0 gives 18. It is impossible for $x$ to be any random value

Comment: Such problems can be difficult to solve, and your approach is not quite up to the task.  You are hoping to show the polynomial $P(x)$ is the square of some (quadratic) polynomial, but if that were so, then every integer $x$ would make $P(x)$ a perfect square.  As @imranfat points out, this is just not so.  The problem is to find integer (or positive integer, if your last Comment is correct) solutions to $y^2 = x^4 -4x^3-22x^2-36x+18$.  It is possible that *factoring* $P(x)$ will help with this Diophantine problem.

Comment: Btw this polynomial is irreducible, let alone being a perfect square(for every $x$).

Comment: It is possible that reducing mod $p$ may help a bit; for instance, reducing mod $3$ shows $x$ must be congruent to $0$ or $2$ mod $3$. Not sure how helpful this will be though

Comment: Reducing mod 4 shows that $x$ must be odd.

Comment: And mod 5 gives $x\equiv3\pmod5$.

Comment: For sufficiently large $x$, we have $ (x^2 - 2 x - 14)^2\le P (x)\le (x^2 - 2 x - 2)^2$.

Answer (score 7):

As Jyrki Lahtonen mentioned in comments, my bounds can be improved to

$$(x^2-2x-14)^2 < P(x) < (x^2-2x-13)^2,$$

or in expanded form:

$$196 + 56 x - 24 x^2 - 4 x^3 + x^4 < 18 - 36 x - 22 x^2 - 4 x^3 + x^4 < 169 + 52 x - 22 x^2 - 4 x^3 + x^4$$

for sufficiently large values of $x$ ($x \ge 48$ in first inequality, $x \ge -1$ in the second one). But these bounds are actually squares of adjacent integers, so after inspection of finitely many cases ($x = 1, 2, \ldots, 47$) we can surelz say that $P(x)$ is never a square.

Comment: Can it be a square when $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: @Gribouillis I don't think so, you can try to show it with a similar argument.

Comment: Sweet answer +1

Answer (score 4):

If $x$ is an integer, then
$$x^4-4x^3-22x^2-36x+18$$
$\qquad$is congruent to $2$ mod $4$ if $x$ is even,

$\qquad$and is congruent to $5$ mod $8$ if $x$ is odd,

hence can't be a perfect square.

(Even squares are congruent to $0$ mod $4$, and odd squares are congruent to $1$ mod $8$.)

Some details . . .

If $x$ is even, all the terms are multiples of $4$ except $18$, so
\begin{align*}
&x^4-4x^3-22x^2-36x+18\\[4pt]
\equiv\;&18\;(\text{mod}\;4)\\[4pt]
\equiv\;&2\;(\text{mod}\;4)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
If $x$ is odd, then $x^2 \equiv 1\;(\text{mod}\;8)$, hence
\begin{align*}
&x^4-4x^3-22x^2-36x+18\\[4pt]
\equiv\;&x^4-4x^3-6x^2-4x+2\;(\text{mod}\;8)\\[4pt]
\equiv\;&(x^2)^2-4(x^2)x-6x^2-4x+2\;(\text{mod}\;8)\\[4pt]
\equiv\;&(1)^2-4(1)x-6(1)-4x+2\;(\text{mod}\;8)\\[4pt]
\equiv\;&-3-8x\;(\text{mod}\;8)\\[4pt]
\equiv\;&5\;(\text{mod}\;8)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}